# How can i consume WS on server from mobile is not in the same network?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I have a WebService published on a server. I want to consume(invoke) this WS 
from mobile(mobile Application) which is not in the same network.I want to access this WS through internet 3G.How can i do this in windows mobile 5.0 and Compact framework??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the web service in the same way you would access it using a normal c# application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446547.aspx

Comment: but there is no any connection between mobile and the server(local network) and the WS and Mobile App not on the same machine.How the mobile can consume the WS??

Comment: you have to put your web service on the web to be consumed by your mobile phone or if you want to consume the one on your "private" server you can connect you phone to your machine and deploy the application on your phone

Comment: How can i put the web service on the web??
and if do so the previous method for consuming will work well??

Comment: you need to have a web host/provider where you can published your web service that will be accessible by 3G somethihng like:
www.MyhostingProvider.com/Myservice.asmx

Comment: in the mobile app i have to add additional code to provide consuming web service through 3G??

Comment: There is not additional code. When on your mobile project you right click add service reference/web service you have to specify a Path which must be reachable by the device. Now if you are using the 3G the web service must be accessible over internet. This won't change the code you need to write or the way how you can add the service reference

Comment: You have answered my question.Thanks alot Eng.Massimiliano Peluso